# rebar dependency without repository

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have rebar project with dependencies, so after clean when I run rebar compile, it downloads dependencies (for git runs git clone, looks like), runs configure for them and then compiles everything. Can I somehow make those dependencies local? I mean to skip downloading them and directly run configure there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
rsync option and specify the file path

```
{rsync, "file:///foo/bar/baz"}
```

is the shape of it as long as I remember